# Android - Menu items are not shown on the toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu, menu-items

I have the problem that my menu items on my toolbar are not shown. Specifically, I have one menu item called 'Settings' that encapsulates all other menu items which I want to show when the 'Settings' icon is clicked. But when that icon is clicked, the list of other menu items are not shown to the user.

Here is my `my_menu.xml`:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
                android:menuCategory="secondary"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_login"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/loginOrLogout"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_first_fragment_icon"
                android:menuCategory="secondary"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/first_fragment_text"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_second_fragment"
                android:menuCategory="secondary"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
                android:title="@string/second_fragment_text"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Here, is my `MainActivity.kt` class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val navController by lazy{ findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)}

    private val appBarConfiguration by lazy {
        AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.firstFragment), binding.drawerLayout)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        setupNavigationComponents(navController)
        setupNavControllerListener()
    }

    private fun setupNavigationComponents(navController: NavController) {
        binding.apply {
            toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
            navView?.setupWithNavController(navController)
            bottomNavView?.setupWithNavController(navController)
        }
    }

    private fun setupNavControllerListener() {
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->

            if(destination.id in arrayOf(
                    R.id.firstFragment)){
                toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
                bottom_nav_view?.visibility = View.GONE
                nav_view?.visibility = View.GONE
            }else{
                toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                bottom_nav_view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                nav_view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean =
        /*
        * Have the NavigationUI look for an action or destination matching the menu
        * item id and navigate there if found.
        * Otherwise, bubble up to the parent.
        * */
        item.onNavDestinationSelected(findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment))
               || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
       // Allows NavigationUI to support proper up navigation or the drawer layout
       // drawer menu, depending on the situation
        return findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment).navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
    }
}
```

In the following, I show a screenshot of the right top of my screen where you can see the 'Settings' icon:

[image]

When I click on that icon, I get this result:

[image]

As you can see, no menu item is shown to the user. The weird thing is that when I click somewhere inside the 'opened white box', then the app navigates to the corresponding fragment. But the items are not shown, why ?

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: have you tried changing the app's default theme to dark?

Comment: If it actually responses your clicking, that means it's the visual problem, make sure the text color is not white.